# Check if the request is already done on promise

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, angular8

I have this function in a file :

```
setToStorage() {
    this.settingsService.getSettings().then((settings: any) => {
        localStorage.setItem('const', JSON.stringify(settings));
    });
}
```

Now in another file I have :

```
if (!localStorage.getItem(STORAGE_ACCOUNT_ATTRIBUTES)) {
        this.accountService.setToStorage();
}
const account = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('const'));
```

The question is how to know if `setToStorage` is done, before get `const` from local storage ?
Because if I do `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('const'))` but `setToStorage()` is not finished I will have an empty value. Please help me. Thx in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example using a function buffer and a boolean state variable.

When Set is not called yet, we will store the Get calls into an array and it wait.

When the Set finally get called, we will resolve all the stored Get calls.

The code below got created quickly and is largely improvable.

- Use an utilitarian function that will be capable to handle the synchronous calls to your functions (Set/Get) providing the functions pointers

```js
function getRndInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

class LocalStorage {
  constructor() {
    this.valueHasBeenInitialized = false;

    // Keep the functions that are waiting for the values to be initialized
    this.functionsKeeper = [];
  }

  // Call all the functions that are waiting to be resolved
  unlockKeptFunctions() {
    this.functionsKeeper.forEach(({
      func,
      resolve,
    }) => {
      func.call(this, resolve);
    });

    this.functionsKeeper = [];
  }

  setToStorage() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('> Resolve setToStorage');

        // INSERT THE CONTENT OF THE SET FUNCTION HERE **

        this.valueHasBeenInitialized = true;

        this.unlockKeptFunctions();

        resolve();
      }, getRndInteger(1500, 3000));
    });
  }

  /**
   * We want the get to be executed only after a setToStorage
   */
  getFromStorage() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      const func = (r) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log('> Resolve getFromStorage');

          // INSERT THE CONTENT OF THE GET FUNCTION HERE **

          r();
        }, getRndInteger(500, 1800));
      };

      if (!this.valueHasBeenInitialized) {
        console.log('getFromStorage() is waiting \
 for setFromStorage to be called');

        // Wait until the value has been initialized
        return this.functionsKeeper.push({
          func,
          resolve,
        });
      }

      func(r);
    });
  }
}

// Call get and set asynchronously
(async() => {
  const localStorage = new LocalStorage();

  await Promise.all([
    localStorage.getFromStorage(),
    localStorage.getFromStorage(),
    localStorage.getFromStorage(),
    localStorage.getFromStorage(),
    localStorage.setToStorage(),
  ]);
})();
```